# Grails - restarting Rabbitmq plugin consumers by calling method on plugin class

Tags: grails, rabbitmq

I am using the Grails Rabbitmq Native plugin.  When I launch the application, I don't want the RMQ consumers to be automatically started, so in my Config.groovy I have defined:

```
rabbitmq.enabled == false
```

The code within doWithSpring() (https://github.com/budjb/grails-rabbitmq-native/blob/master/RabbitmqNativeGrailsPlugin.groovy#L114) means that certain wiring isn't carried out if this flag is false.

At some point, I want to be able to start the RMQ system up.  I'd like to call a method defined within the plugin class, such as restartRabbitContext() (https://github.com/budjb/grails-rabbitmq-native/blob/master/RabbitmqNativeGrailsPlugin.groovy#L231) to start up the RMQ consumers.  I think I will need to carry out some of the wiring myself.

Is there a way to do this?  What is the import required to be able to access the plugin class's methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the [GrailsPluginManager](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/GrailsPluginManager.html) to access your plugin by name using [getGrailsPlugin](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/GrailsPluginManager.html#getGrailsPlugin(java.lang.String)). From there you should be able to access the plugin as a [GrailsPlugin](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/GrailsPlugin.html) and access the public methods defined in the plugin itself.

The `GrailsPluginManager` can be obtained though the `grailsApplication` such as: `grailsApplication.pluginManager`. In the very rare event you can't use DI you can always fall back to [Holders](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/Holders.html) to get to the `GrailsPluginManager` (though this is a very rare case).

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much for such a prompt response!